# HTML video player wont play stream

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js, m3u8

So what I'm trying to do is have a html video player play a m3u8 stream.
I have tried multiple players and none of them seems to be able to play the stream.
Normally I would be thinking that the stream is not working, but VLC plays it just fine.

Here is just one snippet I have tried it with:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.10.2/alt/video-js-cdn.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.10.2/video.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/3.0.2/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay>
            <source src="https://list.iptvcat.com/my_list/s/be001cbd19007cd3d1da1cf3e39b425a.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong and maybe what VLC does that I am not doing?

Comment: m3u8 format is not supported in source

Comment: Your video-js code (v5.x) is 'ancient'...about 5 years old.  Try using one of the 7.x versions.  https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases

Comment: @AnujSharma Yes M3U8 is not supported as a source (it is a text file, not video data) but here, the Video-JS library itself will later extract that path from `<source>` and then parse it to display the actual video file(s).

Comment: This m3u8 is not HLS

Answer (score 1):

> *"I have tried multiple players and none of them seems to be able to play the stream".*

Your video is coming from an **HTTP** link but your player/server are running in **HTTPS**.
Browsers do not like processing **mixed content** (secure vs non-secure URL) in the same page.

**Explained**:

- Your link is HTTPS for the M3U8 file
- The M3U8 is a playlist text file giving link(s) to the video data.
- The video link is: http://tvalb.xyz:8080/9rht8uKGJs/sBN1pWJUhQ/3456?checkedby:iptvcat.com
- Notice the **HTTP** only URL? That's why those web players stop trying here.

**Solution** is to use a PHP script running from your HTTPS server to `readFile` the video link back to your MPEG-TS video player. Your player will see the `.src` as being from your server (is the PHP file) but obviously that same PHP script is just streaming back the video bytes it reads from the other HTTP link.
 PHP does not care about HTTP vs HTTPS, it just reads file bytes if they exist.

**(2)** Your code is incomplete... You need to assign the video tag (by its ID) to VideoJS.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.10.2/alt/video-js-cdn.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.10.2/video.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/3.0.2/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="myVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay>
            <source src="https://list.iptvcat.com/my_list/s/be001cbd19007cd3d1da1cf3e39b425a.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
        </video>
    </body>
    
    <script>
    
    var player = videojs("myVideo");
    //player.play(); //# test playback
    
    </script>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Never did anything similar to what you provided as solution. How would I use a PHP script, that does something like that?

Comment: _"How would I use a PHP script"_ okay you'll have to test if PHP is even supported by your server (it should be if you're paying for a server, but free web space might not offer it)... On your server, put a file called `test.php` which contains the following code text `<?php echo 'PHP is working...'; ?>` ... Test it by opening the HTTP link to your file and IF the page should show only 3 words saying `PHP is working...` it means you can use PHP.